# Problem with a simple Fit

Tags: fitting

I have defined two functions to fit $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{x^2-b^2}}$ and $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$.

```
fitSingularity[listFit_] := 
  Module[{res, startVal1, model, a, b, fit},
   startVal1 = listFit[[1]][[1]]; Print[startVal1];
   res = Sqrt[(listFit[[6]][[1]]^2 - startVal1^2)]*listFit[[6]][[2]];
   model = a/Sqrt[(x^2 - b^2)];
   fit = FindFit[listFit[[2 ;; -1]], 
     model, {{a, res}, {b, startVal1}}, x];
   a = a /. fit;
   b = b /. fit;
   {a, b}
   ];

fitSingularity2[listFit_] := Module[{res, startVal1, model, a, b, fit},
   startVal1 = listFit[[-1]][[1]]; Print[N[startVal1]];
   res = Sqrt[(startVal1^2 - listFit[[6]][[1]]^2)]*listFit[[6]][[2]]; 
   Print[N[res]];
   model = a/Sqrt[(b^2 - x^2)];
   fit = FindFit[listFit[[2 ;; -1]], 
     model, {{a, res}, {b, startVal1}}, x];
   a = a /. fit;
   b = b /. fit;
   {a, b}
   ];
```

To realize the fits I create a list. In the first case with the following code everything is working nicely

```
g[x_] := a/Sqrt[x^2 - b^2]
a = 1; b = 2;
list1 = Table[{x, g[x]}, {x, 1.999, 4, 0.1}];
Show[Plot[g[x], {x, 2, 4}], ListPlot[list1, PlotStyle -> Green]]
fitSingularity[list1]
```

But in the second case I obtain an error and I do not know why (it should not be so different than for the first case)

```
f[x_] := a/Sqrt[b^2 - x^2]
a = 1; b = 2;
list2 = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 1.999, 0.01}];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}], ListPlot[list2, PlotStyle -> Green]]
fitSingularity2[list2]
```

I would like to mention that I implement this to be sure I can fit the function well, but I need to use this fit in a much more complicated case (inside a numerical function that is supposed to have a singularity of the form $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{x^2-b^2}}$ or $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may work this out by establishing a region where the square roots are positive.  I'm using `Reduce[ ]` here, but any bounding method will work:

```
sqRootG[x_, b_] := x^2 - b^2
sqRootF[x_, b_] := b^2 - x^2
g[x_] := a/Sqrt[sqRootG[x, b]]
f[x_] := a/Sqrt[sqRootF[x, b]]
listg = Rest@Table[{x, g[x] /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}}, {x, 1.999, 4, 0.01}];
listf = Rest@Table[{x, f[x] /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}}, {x, 0, 1.999, 0.01}];
sg = Reduce[And @@ Thread[sqRootG[#, b] & /@ listg[[All, 1]] > 0], {a, b}, Reals]; 
sf = Reduce[And @@ Thread[sqRootF[#, b] & /@ listf[[All, 1]] > 0], {a, b}, Reals];
NonlinearModelFit[listg, {g[x], sg}, {a, b}, x, 
                  Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}]["BestFitParameters"]
NonlinearModelFit[listf, {f[x], sf}, {a, b}, x, 
                  Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}]["BestFitParameters"]

(*
{a -> 1., b -> 2.}
{a -> 1., b -> 2.}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is `NonlinearModelFit` better than `FindFit`?? I am not sure I completely understand the `And @@ Thread[sqRootG[#, b] & /@ listg[[All, 1]] > 0]` part, I will try to read the help more carefully. Thanks again

Comment: As I state below (comment to Jack LaVigne),  I try your code with a `FindFit[listf, {f[x], sf}, {{a, 1}, {b, 1.99}}, x]` and get the same error message as I had initially with basically no value returned. So now I am not sure the problem comes from the constraint but probably on `FindFit`. What do you think?

Comment: In fact now I saw that only `NonlinearModelFit` together with the constraint is working for this simple example. Thank you very much. However, when I implement it in my more complicated numerical function (the one I mention at the end of my question), your suggestion does not work (even with the `Reduce` etc...). I obtain an error `Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0.^0.5 encountered."` I don't know what to do.

Comment: My other question related to the more complex case was posted here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95220/problem-with-fit-on-a-numerical-function

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but a comment that is too long to fit in a comment space.

The goal is to elaborate on belisarius's answer.

Copy and execute the code up to `NonLinearModelFit[...` from belisarius's answer.

`sg` evaluates to be

```
-2.001 < b < 2.001
```

The intent is to use it as a constraint in `NonlinearModelFit`.

To break down the complete expression

```
sg = Reduce[And @@ Thread[sqRootG[#, b] & /@ listg[[All, 1]] > 0], {a, b}, Reals]
```

It is helpful to start with the inner expression and evaluate it step by step. In the example I will only show the first four terms of the result.

`listg[[All,1]]` takes the first term (i.e., x) from `listg` pairs.

```
{2.001, 2.011, 2.021, 2.031, ...}
```

Next using these input values

```
sqRootG[#, b] & /@ listg[[All, 1]]
```

makes a new list of x^2 - b^2 using the x value from above.

```
{4.004 - b^2, 4.04412 - b^2, 4.08444 - b^2, 4.12496 - b^2, ...}
```

`Thread` adds `>0` to the list.

```
Thread[sqRootG[#, b] & /@ listg[[All, 1]] > 0]
```

and gives

```
{4.004 - b^2 > 0, 4.04412 - b^2 > 0, 4.08444 - b^2 > 0, 
 4.12496 - b^2 > 0, ...}
```

`And` makes it into a single constraint expression.

```
And @@ Thread[sqRootG[#, b] & /@ listg[[All, 1]] > 0]

4.004 - b^2 > 0 && 4.04412 - b^2 > 0 && 4.08444 - b^2 > 0 && 
 4.12496 - b^2 > 0 ...
```

Finally then `Reduce` evaluates this and gives the final constraint expression

```
-2.001 < b < 2.001
```

With regard to `FindFit` the constraint works equally well with that function

```
FindFit[listg, {g[x], sg}, {a, b}, x]
```

Used like this you get a warning message and a result of 0.9999 for a and -2 for b.

You can use the first result to refine the search with starting values

```
FindFit[listg, {g[x], sg}, {{a, 0.99}, {b, 2.}}, x]
```

Which rapidly gives

```
{a -> 1.00001, b -> 2.}
```

Similar remarks apply to the second function.

Comment: Waouh thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. I think belisarius, along with several other high ranking members on this site, is brilliant. I find that frequently I have to do some work (because of my lack of experience) to break down their answer before I  understand the answer in total. The comment was intended to show you a method that I have found helpful.

Comment: Yes your method is very good. I will apply it next time! Thanks again

Comment: Sorry but your statement does not work with the `f` function. I pass `FindFit[listf, {f[x], sf}, {a, b}, x]` and get a wrong values. After I pass `FindFit[listf, {f[x], sf}, {{a, 1}, {b, 2}}, x]` and get the good values but with error message

Comment: Even worse, If I use `FindFit[listf, {f[x], sf}, {{a, 1}, {b, 1.99}}, x]`  (1.99 as a start value instead of 2), I obtain the same error that I had in my initial question with basically no value returned. So finally, I think the problem comes from `FindFit`  not from the constraint. I am still investigating

Comment: If you set the `Method` parameter `FindFit` duplicates `NonLinearModel`. `FindFit[listf, {f[x], sf}, {a, b}, x, 
 Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}]`. Setting the `Method` appears to be a key factor in this problem.

Comment: You are right! With the `Method` option it is working right now. Thank you. However only the simple example provided here is working, with my complicated numerical functions I still obtain the error `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^0.5 encountered`. I will ask another question with this more specific issue

Comment: My other question related to the more complex case was posted here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95220/problem-with-fit-on-a-numerical-function