# Problem with fit on a numerical function

Tags: fitting

My question is related to a previous one: [Problem with simple fit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95156/problem-with-a-simple-fit/95172?noredirect=1#comment257618_95172), where I had a problem to fit a simple analytic function $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$.

The solution proposed in [Problem with simple fit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95156/problem-with-a-simple-fit/95172?noredirect=1#comment257618_95172) is working very well. However when trying to extend this fitting procedure to another (more complex) list, it does not work.

Here is the list of data I want to fit

```
listFit = {{10.063521, 0.075566752}, {10.063533, 
    0.075948022}, {10.063545, 0.076335511}, {10.063557, 
    0.076620465}, {10.063569, 0.077130577}, {10.063581, 
    0.077369663}, {10.063594, 0.077928066}, {10.063606, 
    0.078179029}, {10.063618, 0.078777947}, {10.06363, 
    0.079075133}, {10.063642, 0.079499388}, {10.063654, 
    0.079948343}, {10.063667, 0.080276773}, {10.063679, 
    0.080829161}, {10.063691, 0.08120991}, {10.063703, 
    0.081737999}, {10.063715, 0.082144721}, {10.063727, 
    0.082663574}, {10.06374, 0.083099446}, {10.063752, 
    0.08347671}, {10.063764, 0.084042498}, {10.063776, 
    0.084695357}, {10.063788, 0.085111893}, {10.0638, 
    0.085652364}, {10.063813, 0.086138049}, {10.063825, 
    0.086619555}, {10.063837, 0.087291384}, {10.063849, 
    0.087728427}, {10.063861, 0.088332497}, {10.063873, 
    0.088948531}, {10.063886, 0.089623189}, {10.063898, 
    0.090135636}, {10.06391, 0.09063353}, {10.063922, 
    0.091418646}, {10.063934, 0.091992204}, {10.063946, 
    0.092718055}, {10.063958, 0.093453208}, {10.063971, 
    0.094003733}, {10.063983, 0.094806353}, {10.063995, 
    0.095456824}, {10.064007, 0.096155563}, {10.064019, 
    0.096890442}, {10.064031, 0.097742368}, {10.064044, 
    0.098434713}, {10.064056, 0.099370392}, {10.064068, 
    0.10007115}, {10.06408, 0.10097375}, {10.064092, 
    0.10181072}, {10.064104, 0.10272999}, {10.064117, 
    0.10369551}, {10.064129, 0.1047189}, {10.064141, 
    0.10558052}, {10.064153, 0.10646513}, {10.064165, 
    0.10756963}, {10.064177, 0.10864458}, {10.06419, 
    0.10958263}, {10.064202, 0.11077386}, {10.064214, 
    0.11191695}, {10.064226, 0.11310339}, {10.064238, 
    0.11443975}, {10.06425, 0.11560699}, {10.064262, 
    0.11695356}, {10.064275, 0.11830794}, {10.064287, 
    0.11967723}, {10.064299, 0.12121895}, {10.064311, 
    0.122602}, {10.064323, 0.12411718}, {10.064335, 
    0.12567948}, {10.064348, 0.12756902}, {10.06436, 
    0.12939693}, {10.064372, 0.13123784}, {10.064384, 
    0.13290587}, {10.064396, 0.13504858}, {10.064408, 
    0.13713008}, {10.064421, 0.13917298}, {10.064433, 
    0.14156279}, {10.064445, 0.14412959}, {10.064457, 
    0.14645984}, {10.064469, 0.14905608}, {10.064481, 
    0.15193576}, {10.064494, 0.15481572}, {10.064506, 
    0.15813123}, {10.064518, 0.16150957}, {10.06453, 
    0.16513978}, {10.064542, 0.1690908}, {10.064554, 
    0.1728227}, {10.064566, 0.17751269}, {10.064579, 
    0.18234043}, {10.064591, 0.18726098}, {10.064603, 
    0.19313381}, {10.064615, 0.19974816}, {10.064627, 
    0.20622093}, {10.064639, 0.21374233}, {10.064652, 
    0.22235096}, {10.064664, 0.23229261}, {10.064676, 
    0.24326983}, {10.064688, 0.25589852}, {10.0647, 
    0.2708861}, {10.064712, 0.2892596}, {10.064725, 
    0.31124154}, {10.064737, 0.33955139}};
```

Based on [Problem with simple fit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95156/problem-with-a-simple-fit/95172?noredirect=1#comment257618_95172), I use the following function to fit

```
fitSingularity2[listFit_] := 
  Module[{res, startVal1, sqRootF, model, sf, a, b, fit},
   startVal1 = listFit[[-1]][[1]];
   res = Sqrt[(startVal1^2 - listFit[[6]][[1]]^2)]*listFit[[6]][[2]];
   sqRootF[x_, b_] := b^2 - x^2;
   model = a/Sqrt[sqRootF[x, b]];
   sf = Reduce[
     And @@ Thread[sqRootF[#, b] & /@ listFit[[All, 1]] > 0], {a, b}, 
     Reals];
   fit = NonlinearModelFit[
      listFit[[2 ;; -1]], {model, sf}, {{a, res}, {b, startVal1}}, x, 
      Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}][
     "BestFitParameters"];
   a = a /. fit;
   b = b /. fit;
   {a, b}];
```

But as you can see by passing this to Mathematica

```
fit = fitSingularity2[listFit]
Print[Show[ListPlot[listFit], 
  Plot[fit[[1]]/Sqrt[((fit[[2]])^2 - x^2)], {x, listFit[[1]][[1]], 
    listFit[[-1]][[1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]]
```

that the fit is not correct.
However I am sure that the function has the form of $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$ since by passing this to Mathematica

```
Print[Show[ListPlot[listFit], 
  Plot[0.012/Sqrt[((10.06479`)^2 - x^2)], {x, listFit[[1]][[1]], 
    fit[[2]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]]
```

I superpose correctly the curves.

Comment: You don't need `Print` to display results in _Mathematica_

Comment: Yes you are right. It was previously inside a function it is why the `Print` is here, I forgot to put it out, my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `x` coordinates range are too small and the precision suffers.Just rescale:

```
list = {#1*100, #2} & @@@ listFit;
```

Then use my solution to your other question:

```
sqRootF[x_, b_] := b^2 - x^2
f[x_] := a/Sqrt[sqRootF[x, b]]
sf = Reduce[And @@ Thread[sqRootF[#, b] & /@ list[[All, 1]] > 0], {a, b}, Reals];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[list, {f[x], sf}, {a, b}, x, 
           Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}] // Quiet;
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
Show[ListPlot[list],
     Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[list[[All, 1]]], Max@list[[All, 1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]

(* {a -> 1.2169239244205383`, b -> 1006.4800533971684`} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your parameters are obtained by dividing those `{ a, b }` by 100. If in doubt:

```
Solve[a1/Sqrt[b1^2 - (100 x)^2] == a/Sqrt[b^2 - (x)^2] /.  b -> b1/100, {a}]
(*
 {{a -> a1/100}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, there is one thing that is not clear to me: in the case discussed here the scale is too small and I understand it well. However, for the other kind of singularity ($\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{x^2-b^2}}$) with the same very small scale, a `FindFit` without any constraint is doing the job perfectly (see `fitSingularity` function in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95156/problem-with-a-simple-fit/95172?noredirect=1#comment257618_95172). How is it possible??

Comment: @lambertmular.  All software packages can have the same issues when the first 5 digits of the predictor variable are identical when fitting such models.  Scaling and centering can many times resolve numerical instability issues.  This is not a Mathematica issue.

Comment: @lambertmular.  While the fit looks good by eye, there is still a great deal of patter in the residuals:  `resid = nlm["FitResiduals"];
pred = nlm["PredictedResponse"];
ListPlot[Table[{pred[[i]], resid[[i]]}, {i, Length[pred]}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Predicted", "Residual"}]`.  In other words, there seems to be some thing more than the proposed functional form.

Comment: @Jim Baldwin. That's ok here because what I want to do is to fit the function and calculate the integral of the function analytically close to the singularity. This fit should give a good approximation of the integral. But maybe now, thanks to  you, I understand why `Nintegrate` returns `NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. `when I try to integrate the remaining part of the function. It should be because of the residuals.

Answer (score 5):

Following Belasarius's procedure to locate the constraints one finds that `b` must be > 10.0647.

Plot the error as a function of `a` and `b` near the solution.

`inco[a_, b_] := 
 Total[Map[(#[[2]] - a/Sqrt[b^2 - #[[1]]^2])^2 &, listFit]]`

`Plot[{inco[0.01, b], inco[0.011, b], inco[0.012, b], 
  inco[0.013, b]}, {b, 10.0647, 10.07}, AxesOrigin -> {10.064, 0}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now blow it up

```
Plot[{inco[0.01, b], inco[0.011, b], inco[0.012, b], 
  inco[0.013, b]}, {b, 10.0647, 10.07}, AxesOrigin -> {10.0647, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10.0647, 10.065}, {0, 0.2}},
 Ticks -> {{10.0647, 10.0648, 10.0649, 10.065}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The answer appears to be near 0.012 and 10.0648.

Note also that the error (or incoherence) grows rapidly for values less than 10.0648.

Therefore it looks like a good idea to limit the solution space to a number slightly greater than 10.0647 (for numerical stability purposes).

With these values for constraint and starting value a good solution is derived.

```
FindFit[listFit, {f[x], b > 10.06475}, {{a, 0.013}, {b, 10.065}}, x, 
 Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}]

{a -> 0.0121688, b -> 10.0648}
```

**Rescaling**

As per Belasarius's solution and Jim Baldwin's comment, rescaling helps with this problem.

```
listFitR = {#1*100, #2} & @@@ listFit;
```

Get the constraints

```
sf = Reduce[
  And @@ Thread[sqRootF[#, b] & /@ listFitR[[All, 1]] > 0], {a, b}, 
  Reals]

b < -1006.47 || b > 1006.47
```

Use `FindFit` to get the results.

```
FindFit[listFitR, {f[x], sf}, {a, b}, x, 
 Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}]
```

gives the same results as `NonLinearModelFit`.

```
{a -> 1.21692, b -> 1006.48}
```

For this expression each parameter has to be divided by 100 to go back to the original scale.

```
With[
 {
  xmin = Min[listFit[[All, 1]]],
  xmax = Max[listFit[[All, 1]]]
  },
 Show[
  ListPlot[listFit, PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, Automatic}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. {a -> 0.0121692, b -> 10.0648}],
   {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, but I need to have it automatic to treat a lot of curves that possess the same singularity. Your solution seems good but not suitable for an automatic treatment. Thank you anyway